# GA _trackPageview with user ID

Tags: google-analytics

What is the best way to do a proper _trackPageview in GA but also store the user ID of the push?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-46732147-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'],"/$textRepresentationUserID");
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

At the moment I have just forced the URL to include the variable on the end, but I have read other people say the best way is to use customvariables.. I don't want to leave this running for too long and then find I have a bunch of useless data..

Any tips?

The reason I need to to this is to determine what members of a certain member area on the site are using..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is totally legal, check carefully the GA terms of services.

Anyway the best way to do that, as your friends said, would be to use custom variables:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1,'User ID', '999999', 1]);
```

`999999` is the user ID in this case.

Anyway, any method will actually generate a bunch of data...

Comment: Make sure you do the _setCustomVar BEFORE the _trackPageview so the data get's correctly attached to the pageview.

Comment: Appologies for my newbyness... but wouldn't a pageview and customVar be two sets of data? can you link the two sets together? I did here was an illegal maneuver though so I will go ahead and start using custom vars and see what i get. Thanks for the tips